# replace a fragment from fragment

Tags: java, android

I have ActivityFragment with two Fragment
i can start a fragement from the ActivityFragment using :

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.center_layout, new MyFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

my problem is when trying to replace `MyFragment()`  by an other Fragment in `R.id.center_layout` from `MyFragment()`  class

i tried

```
FragmentTransaction transaction =this.getChildFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.center_layout, client_Ajouter);
transaction.commit();
```

but i get

```
No view found for id 0x7f06000b (center_layout) for fragment Client_Ajouter
```

and thank you.

Comment: sorry for the trouble now it works using '   FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`. Also, if you want to replace the fragment, you should probably be using the `replace` method instead of `add`.